# How can I add the assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0' to my tvOS Xamarin project?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-assembly, tvos

I have a multi-project Xamarin Solution with a .net core 2.0 shared project.

I wanna now add a Xamarin tvOS project to it. I cannot build it, because it says for everything, `Object`, `List`, etc. that the net standard assembly is missing.

If I open the "Edit reference", I cannot select such an assembly.

I already added the NuGet Package `.NETStandard.Library`.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

**Error log**

```
is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0
```

Comment: The introduction of .NET Standard class library renders PCL and shared project obsolete in most cases. Maybe you should now try to migrate.

Comment: Some Xamarin User Group guys said, that the time for PCL is over and now we should use shared .net core projects instead of PCLs. *hm*

Answer (score 0):

Do you have .Net Framework 4.7.1 installed?

[Release notes for 4.7.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/17/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-1/) state:

> .NET Framework support for .NET Standard 2.0 and compiler features

Installing that made my Xamarin project build on VS 2017.